# Squarespace adds a string to the end of my url links. How do I get rid of this?

Tags: url, hyperlink, stripe-payments, squarespace

I'm trying to add a string `?basic` to the end of a button link on my squarespace page. The button sends clicks to url `https://app.myapp.com/users/new` and I'd like it to be `https://app.myapp.com/users/new?basic` so I can parse the end after the question mark as an indicator of which "plan" they've clicked.

The problem is, squarespace is affixing the below string to the end of the url from my button.

- &_gl=1*6h4b53*_ga*MTk0NjI3NzY2NC4xNjg5NDQ2ODc5*_ga_EHN5JF88RC*MTY4OTU2MDM5Ny4zLjEuMTY4OTU2MDU2Ny4wLjAuMA..

Is there a way around this? My app lives on the subdomain and the goal is to be able to tell which plan the user clicked on from the squarespace hosted page. The squarespace hosted page is 2 pages prior to where I start my stripe checkout on my web app.